# boost::serialization and factory pattern design

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, factory-pattern

I have `protected` my constructors in a component-based game engine skeleton I'm working on, so that `Component`s are created in a `GameSystem` that handles ownership assignment and attaches them to `GameObject`s. The protected constructor of a `Component` takes a `GameObject&`, since its owner will always exist throughout the `Component`'s lifetime.

I tried to apply serialization to `Component` classes by overriding the `load_construct_data()` and `save_construct_data()` functions and making them friends of `Component`, but I would end up with something like this:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void load_construct_data(Archive& ar, Component* t, const unsigned int file_version)
{
        // Retrieve data from archive required to construct new instance
        GameObject gameObject; // This is illegal since GameObject() is protected.
        ar >> gameObject;
        // Invoke inplace constructor to initialize instance of my_class
        ::new(t)Component(gameObject);
}
```

I can create a `GameObject` through `GameSystem` as well, or make `load_construct_data` a friend of `GameObject`. I don't like the proliferation of friendships, but does the first option make sense? Would the serialization library somehow keep track of the object, even though it wasn't created through its constructor? Remember I need to load each object only once.

Or does it call for a major redesign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made `GameObject`s have a public constructor to allow access. Solves the issue, if in a somewhat clunky manner.